# Visa refused because I already have a seaman's visa

Tags: schengen, visa-refusals, schengen-visas

I have a Spanish Schengen visa, valid from October 19 2016 to October 20 2017. I'm a seaman. I disembarked recently in a Schengen country, in July, and I also disembarked earlier in Spain.

Now I plan to visit Germany but, when I applied for a tourist visa, was refused. The reason given was that my Schengen seafarers' visa has not yet expired.

Does this mean I can use my seaman's visa to visit Germany? Or, should I have it cancelled and then re-apply for the German Schengen visa?

Comment: You can use your Spanish visa to travel to Germany, that's one of the points of the Schengen system.

Comment: @phoog Sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: Is your existing visa a multiple-entry type C visa valid for "Estados Schengen"? If so, there is no problem -- it is valid for _all kinds of_ short visits to anywhere in the Schengen area within its period of validity. If not, please describe how you observe that it differs from a multiple-entry type C visa.

Answer (score 4):

In the [website of Ministry of Foreign Affairs and Cooperation of Spain](http://www.exteriores.gob.es/Embajadas/SINGAPUR/en/Embajada/ServiciosConsulares/Pages/Seamen-Visa.aspx) it's stated:

> ### Seamen Visa Requirements​
>
> Only seamen who are nationals from a country which is required to have a valid visa to enter the Schengen Space need to
>   apply for a transit visa and if they intend to:
>
> - join a ship that is (or will be) in a Schengen port
> - land with the aim of join another ship that is (or will arrive) in a Schengen port
> - land due to sickness, repatriation, **holiday** and so on.

So from the above reference it's clear that with a seamen' Schengen visa one can land in Schengen Area for holidays (tourism).

That being said, you don't need to revoke your Schengen visa, because with a Schengen visa (including the seamen Schengen visa obtained from a **Spanish** embassy) you can visit all the countries inside Schengen Area (including **Germany**). The states within Schengen Area are listed below:

Austria, Belgium, Czechia, Denmark, Estonia, Finland, France, **Germany**, Greece, Hungary, Iceland, Italy, Latvia, Liechtenstein, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Malta, the Netherlands, Norway, Poland, Portugal, Slovakia, Slovenia, **Spain**, Sweden and Switzerland.

Here is the map of all Schengen states from [European Commission website](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/schengen_visa_en):

[image]

Comment: But, is OP allowed to use a *seaman* visa to travel for *tourism*?

Comment: I fully agree that it's not country-specific, and that OP would be allowed to enter Germany or any other Schengen country *for seafaring purposes*.  But it's not clear to me that tourism would be included.  There's an even "weaker" activity on the scale: transit.  And it appears to me that the seaman visa could be considered a sort of extended transit visa.

Comment: @gdrt: No, that is wrong. The Schengen ruleset _does not allow_ member states to issue "transit visas" in forms other than uniform Schengen visas.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, mates. I've edited the answer to include the clarification about seamen visa for tourism with a reference to Spanish Foreign Affairs Ministry.

Comment: @gdrt "land due to ... holiday" - the key word here to me is *land* - it implies to me that this is meant to deal with them landing from a ship in their capacity as seamen, then taking a holiday before going home or rejoining a ship, not travelling to the EU independently at a later date, as a tourist, purely for tourist purposes. But it's not really clear either way from that summary...