# Seafarer schengen visa

Tags: schengen-visas

Can I use my Netherlands Schengen Visa (seafarer) as a tourist visa. It is a multi entry for 5 years valid til 2022. I am planning a trip to Europe for a holiday.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/99536/visa-refused-because-i-already-have-a-seamans-visa